# how do i call class in scss in type script or (.ts)

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I have created class in scss and i want to call it inside my type script or (ts)

User Story:
*As a teacher, I want to see a student become disabled (Low opacity and unclickable) so that I know who are failed in my subject.*

```
.student{
    opacity: 0px;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

ts

```
???
```

how i call scss class to my ts?

html

```
<container>
    <div class="student">
        <div class="move-center flex-align-center">
             <p class="cont-body">Student name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean with "calling". You can't execute a css (or scss in your case) class, because it describes how something should look and does not describe behavior.
What you can do is assigning a scss class to an HTML-Element in TypeScript.

```
document.querySelector("css-selector").classList.add("student")
```

This will select first element (use querySelectorAll to select all elements) with the given css-selector. Then you add the css class to your classList attribute on the HTMl-Element you get from document.querySelector.

Comment: what is that `css-selector`?

Comment: Thats a Placeholder for a CSS-Selector like "#my-id" to select the element in the DOM (Document Object Model). Those are the "things before the '{' in your CSS / SCSS Code". Like the ".student" in your code example. You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors
If you have any more questions about it, just ask :-)

Comment: so basically i should do this document.`querySelector("student").classList.add("student")` ??

Comment: Yeah kinda. Your Current css-selector would select a student tag like "<student></student>". You need to add a period "." in front of to get an element with the class student e.g. `<div class='student'></div>`. But in this case you would add a class "student" to a element that already has the class "student". 
If you want to add a e.g. `disabled` class to your `<div class='student'></div>` you could use `querySelector(".student").classList.add("disabled")` The disabled class not could contain the styling to mark a student as failed.